# changing null to not null in postgresql via c#

Tags: c#, postgresql

I have a PostgreSql DB connected to Visual Studio. I want to change a column(what column I want) from null to not null via Visual Studio. How I can do that? Can't find this on internet.

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-altertable.html

Comment: @mjwills I don't know how to do it. I'm a little rockie ^^

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
SqlConnection sqlConnection1 = new SqlConnection("Your Connection String");
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
SqlDataReader reader;

cmd.CommandText = "ALTER TABLE YourTableName ALTER COLUMN YourColumnName DROP NOT NULL;";
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.Connection = sqlConnection1;

sqlConnection1.Open();

reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
// Data is accessible through the DataReader object here.

sqlConnection1.Close();
```

Comment: Where I should put that?